# Assigning reference argument to local variable

Tags: c++, reference

Does the following code invoke any type of implementation-defined or undefined behavior? I'm unsure how the interaction with the reference is working and my Google/SO searches are coming up empty:

```
struct S {
    int i;
};

void Fn(S& s_arg) {
    S s_fn{s_arg.i+1};
    s_arg = s_fn;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    S s_main{15};
    Fn(s_main);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm unsure which of the two should occur when the assignment occurs in Fn:

1. The default copy assignment operator of S is invoked on `s_main` (being the target of the `s_arg` reference), copying the data from the local (to `Fn`) `s_fn` into `main`'s local `s_main` (via the `s_arg` reference, making everything proper and well-defined.
2. The reference itself is assigned and now refers to `Fn`'s local `s_fn`. `Fn` is now returning a reference to local data and the program is now just waiting for another function to be called from `main`, overwriting `Fn`'s local `s_fn` and causing general mayhem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no UB here, the reference points to s_main and you are assigning to the value of s_fn to s_arg (which is pointing to s_main) and all is well. Remember that references (unlike pointers) once initialized cannot point to another region in memory which means the second case you mentioned cannot happen.

Comment: Ah, that's what I get for treating references as glorified pointers I suppose. I'm guessing that the reason they cannot point to another region in memory is that because like this case any assignment of the reference always invokes the assignment operator of the object being referred to?

Comment: @user2555367: It is better to think of references as alias (another name) rather than pointers.

Answer (score 3):

References (unlike pointers) cannot have their "address" changed. Therefore, the assignment operator is invoked.

Answer (score 2):

C++ references cannot be "reseated" or made to refer to a different object than they did initially.  This rules out your possibility #2.  The code is OK.